# Declaring a default templated function

Tags: c++, default-template-argument

Suppose I have the following:

```
// Foo.h
struct Foo {};

// Bar.h
struct Bar {
    template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Foo, T>::value>::type>
    void foobar();
};

// Bar.hpp
// ...?
void Bar::foobar() {}
```

How do I declare the `foobar` function on Bar.hpp?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename> void Bar::foobar() {}` ?

Comment: "*How do I declare the foobar function on Bar.cpp?*" - you don't. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/)

Comment: Question updated/edited.

Comment: why do you want a separate implementation? Why not implementing it at the point of declaration?

Comment: @bolov very long history. That'd need another thread :)

Answer (score 0):

The default argument must be specified just once. So do this:

```
template <class T, class>
void Bar::foobar() {}
```